# Css counters difference in output for marker and before pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

I am going through this [link](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#nested-counters) to understand more on counters and how nested counter work,

I have the css and html as following

```css
<style>
   ol {
      counter-reset: my-counter 0;
      list-style-type: none;
   }
   li::before {
     content: counters(my-counter, '.'); 
     counter-increment: my-counter;
   }
</style>
```

With the html as

```html
<ol>
  <li> First
     <ol>
        <li> Eleven </li>
        <li> Twelve </li>
     </ol>
  </li>
  <li> Second
    <ol>
       <li> Twenty-one </li>
       <li> Twenty-two </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Here i am getting the content as expected, like `1` and `1.1`, however changing the `before` to `marker` pseudo element i.e `li::marker` gives a value like `0` and `0.0`.

Although when i use only this css, the output is as expected

```css
   li::marker {content: counters(list-item, '.') ' ';}
```

I couldn't get why the before and marker pseudo elements are generating different output for this list.

Comment: Because marker is a pseudo element it needs the content in this instance. Styling of the marker is limited at present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to the allowed properties within `::marker`. `content` is allowed but not `counter-increment` so it's working but without incrementing the counter.

If you move the incrementation to `li` it works:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: my-counter 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::marker {
  content: counters(my-counter, '.');
}

li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> First
    <ol>
      <li> Eleven </li>
      <li> Twelve </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li> Second
    <ol>
      <li> Twenty-one </li>
      <li> Twenty-two </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

More detail about the allowed properties can be found in the Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#marker-properties